# Can I use an Arduino "library" that's NOT in the std library location?

Tags: arduino, shared-libraries, include-path

I have a project where two Arduinos are talking across a serial connection.
The pair of related sketches are in my proper sketch dir:

```
c:\sketches
   \test
      \one
         one.ino
      \two
         two.ino
```

These compile & upload & function just fine.

But because they are related, and because the comms protocol is identical in both directions, I want to have a common CPP class to manage the conversation. The twist is that I *don't* want to put this a std Arduino library location, I want it to be a "private" library that's visible to and used by only these two sketches.
What I want is this:

```
c:\sketches
   \test
      \common
         testcomms.cpp
         testcomms.h
```

and then have both one.ino and two.ino include the .cpp and .h.

This is pretty straightforward in a standard "C" project, but I can't get Arduino to honor it.

I'm not an Arduino newbie - I realize that the Arduino IDE is really just a preprocessor and that it has its own rules on include locations, etc. And I've read many other SO posts on Arduino and include paths and libs, so please don't flame me. I'm simply wondering if anyone has successfully created the arrangement that I outline above, and if so, hoping that they'd be so kind as to share their trick.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck dropping to make and avr-g++ than trying to bend the Arduino IDE to your will.

Comment: @Ignacio - agreed, at some point that's the real solution. But I'm in the mode of "just trying to get my Arduino-based project done" and not currently able to take the time hit to retool.